# A quick way for decomposing fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, partial-fractions

The complete method for decomposing fractions is obvious . For example $y = \frac{2x+1}{(x-1)(x+3)} = \frac{a}{x-1} + \frac{b}{x+3} = \frac{a(x+3) + b(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+3)} \Rightarrow $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b= 2  \\ 
3a - b = 1 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$  \Rightarrow a = 3/4 , b= 5/4 $

But I was interested in finding a quick way . So I did another operation : 
$y = \frac{2x+1}{(x-1)(x+3)} = \frac{a}{x-1} + \frac{b}{x+3} = \frac{a(x+3) + b(x-1)}{(x-1)(x+3)} \Rightarrow 2x+1 = a(x+3) +b(x-1)    \ \ \star$

Put $x= 1$ then $a = 3/4$ and $x = -3$ then $b =5/4 $ .
I was wondering why this method works correctly because the relation $\star$ works for all values except $1$ and $-3$ . I've tried many examples and strangely this method was correct all the time .

Comment: Your method uses 'partial fractions': http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thank you but that article hasn't explained why it works .

Comment: It works because on expanding $\star$ we get $$2x+1=(a+b)x+(3a-b)$$ and equating like terms we have two equations which are the same as those obtained in your complete method.